# Communicate serial data with ethernet on Xilinx

Tags: uart, ethernet, xilinx

Is it possible to communicate serial data traffic via ethernet (usually we use uart-usb for that purpose)?

I am talking about Xilinx Ultrascale+ based board [ZCU102, Avnet Ultrazed.]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's very possible. If you're already are using an FPGA, why is that even a question? "Serial data" is just… data.

Easiest solution: your ZCU is based on a MPSoC with an integrated application processor, typically running Linux. Just exchange the serial data from FPGA to the CPU core, e.g. through the UARTLITE AXI core, and send it using a TCP socket. The typical abstraction for a serial interface to your FPGA is a *character device*, and streaming from/to that over TCP takes nothing more than one of the [examples from the `socat` documentation](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#EXAMPLES). Don't quote me on that, but something like `socat TCP4-LISTEN:12345 /dev/ttyUL0,rawer` would do the trick of opening TCP port 12345, and allowing whoever connects to that to read and write from/to the uartlite interface.

If your serial data is high-rate, or if for some reason you **really** cannot use the application processor (don't come up with excuses like "I'm not proficient with Linux", writing hardware will be harder than learning that), then you'd need to implement a network interface in your FPGA:

Add a simple ethernet MAC IP core there (there's a free license for that included in your ZCU102), and send and receive your data as ethernet frames, or add one of the multiple open source UDP/IP or TCP/IP stacks on top, and send IP packets.

---

Generally, this all reads like you're trying to do something strange: this is an FPGA, with a Linux computer in one SoC. If you want to exchange the kind of information you typically exchange via an external UART, well, just follow the Xilinx tutorials on how to exchange data between PS (i.e., the ARM CPU) and PL (i.e., the FPGA). That's the whole point of these SoCs!

Comment: Hi! great. I would say that my purpose is basically debug via serial terminal with ethernet [Until now I use uart-usb]. So you mean I obligated to use petalinux in order to implement this?

Comment: no, nobody forces you to use petalinux. But it's what Xilinx offers themselves.

Comment: Add a simple ethernet MAC IP core >> Can i use GEM [inside PS] and the built in Marvell PHY?

Comment: I guess you can! I have no specific knowledge of either. Again, doing this in the PL is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: I was digging the issue a little bit. Turns out I will probably need driver to communicate between ethernet and terminal.